# How can I make an img go out of page when a new div slide in?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a new site, in this site I have a navbar with a menu indicator on the left side, a logo in the middle and possibly some other things on the right side.

I set up a jQuery action so that when you click on the Menu indicator a new div (the menu) slide in. If I surf the website from a PC the code doesn't have any problems (yet), but when I open the menu from mobile the img logo won't go out of the page (in the pc version it stays in the page because there is a lot of space), it will simply get under the menu, making everything look weird.

I know that I can't explain myself very well, so here is a JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/9gx7dzwj/

HTML

```
    <body>
    <div id="menu"><ul>
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <li>Home</li>
        </ul></div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="menuindicator"></div>
        <img id="logo" src="http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg"/>
        </div>
    <div id="main">
        <!--<h1>asdqe</h1>-->

        </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
width: 500px;
margin: 0px;
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
}


#navbar {
height: 2.5em;
background-color: white;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 100%;


}
#logo {
margin-top: -2.75em;
height: 2.5em;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}
#menuindicator {
background-color: black;
width: 2.5em;
height: 2.5em;
margin-left: 0;
z-index: 1;
display: inline-block;
}
#menuindicator img {
margin-top: 0.75em;
margin-right: auto;
width: 1em;
}
#menu {
background-color: dimgrey;
height: 100%;
width: 30em;
float: left;
display: inline;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#menu').hide();
$('#menuindicator').click(function() {
    $('#menu').toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

Everything is the same as wy website, I just added a fixed width to simulate a mobile environment.

Anybody can help?

(There is another thing that's bugging me, why do I have to set a negative top margin to the logo to make it stay in the navbar?)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Yes, I probably can solve the issue just by adding a negative offset with jQuery to the elements in the navbar, but I'm still interested in why this happens

Comment: *Your HTML is invalid.* `h1` cannot be a direct child of `ul`- ***only*** `li` is allowed here.

Comment: @connexo you are right, that's an error I didn't spot, I was in a hurry and I'm just testing things out, thank you!

Comment: Also, if you want to hide anything, including an image, just make the div it is in at overlow:hidden. Then negative or positive margin it. In that case, anything beyond the boundary of the parent div is thenhidden. not wrapped, stretched, etc. That is one way to accomplish such thing.

Comment: @Casey if I put the img in a div and set its overflow to hidden the img just disappears, unless it's outside the navbar, but I want it to be visible inside it

Comment: @Casey great, I fixed the problem in my previous comment, now I just need to center the logo without margin:auto, because in this way the margin are recalculated and the logo never goes outside the screw

Comment: @Casey nope it doesn't leave the screen unfortunately, I have the same problem